# JAX-WS How to hide WSDL in weblogic?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

I create a JAX-WS webservice and deployed it on weblogic 10.3.3. It is deployed succesfully and everything is working fine.

**Now, we want to access webservice by hiding the WSDL. I try to hide the WSDL from weblogic admin console. Goto this location**

```
Deployed application -> Webservice -> Configuration tab
```

**In this tab, by putting "false" in the parameter "WSDL Publish File".**

Saving this created a Plan.xml. The issue arises when I try to activate the changes in Weblogic. Following is the exception that I got:

> An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for
>   details.
>
> Error encountered during prepare phase of deploying WebService module
>   'TB_DBLEGI_SIMULATOR-trunk.war'. Error encountered while deploying
>   WebService module 'TB_DBLEGI_SIMULATOR-trunk.war'. Failed to publish
>   wsdl java.io.IOException: Wsdl file should be placed at META-INF/wsdl,
>   or WEB-INF/wsdl
>
> Wsdl file should be placed at META-INF/wsdl, or WEB-INF/wsdl

In my war, the WSDL is placed inside the WEB-INF/wsdl folder.
Also, I tried to place it at different places but I had no luck.

Comment: It is possible in JAX-RPC. In the annotation @WSDL we have an attribute "exposed". Wi this we can hide the wsdl e.g. @WSDL(exposed = false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always write and register a `Filter` to block access to a given resource.
For example:

```
public class BlockFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        return;
    }
}
```

And register the filter in the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>blockFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>namespace.BlockFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>blockFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*?wsdl</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```